# Expand table with cross apply

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I want to expand a table using cross apply with a list of number as input.
For example, the original table would look like:

| ID |
| --- |
| A |
| B |
| c |

Then, I have a list of random number of unknown length to be passed as a variable, like 1, 2, 3. After this, the table would look like this:

| ID | N |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| A | 3 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| B | 3 |
| C | 1 |
| C | 2 |
| C | 3 |

I tried to do this in Python and then upload the dataframe to database, but the data inserting part took extremely long as the table have millions of rows.
I was wondering if there is an optimal way to do this purely in SSMS and use SQL only?

Comment: FYI SSMS is purely a client interface to SQL Server... so it won't be part of the solution if you are calling SQL Server from code.

Comment: @dhs4402, even if you write this in SSMS, you will need to pass the parameters using your called program. May be using python to call the SP?

Answer (score 5):

Rather than a `CROSS APPLY`, perhaps a `CROSS JOIN` will do.

Example

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID varchar(25))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('A'),('B'),('C')

Declare @String varchar(max)='1,2,3'

Select *
 From  @YourTable 
 Cross Join string_split(@String,',')
```

**Results**

```
ID  value
A   1
A   2
A   3
B   1
B   2
B   3
C   1
C   2
C   3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Stored procedure (SP) and call the procedure in Python code. Then you need to provide a list of integers to the SQL stored procedure as an input.  String_split function can be used if you are using SQL server 2016 or above. Else you have to write a function to split the string.
You can call this in python function. Get a input values to a list and then assign the list to a string variable and pass the variable to SP as a parameter.

```
   --EXEC Insert_data '1,2,3,4'
   CREATE PROCEDURE Insert_data( 
   -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @Input_list AS VARCHAR(MAX)
    )
   AS
   BEGIN
       -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
       -- interfering with SELECT statements.
      SET NOCOUNT ON;

     SELECT 
     *
    INTO #Temp_integers
    FROM
    string_split(@Input_list,',') 

     DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Input_Values
 
 
      SELECT A.ID
       , CAST(B.[value] AS INT) AS [Value]
      INTO Input_Values 
      FROM  Temp_values  A
      CROSS JOIN  #Temp_integers B
      

       SELECT * 
       FROM Input_Values
       ORDER BY ID,[Value]

END
GO
```

[image: Sample Output]